# I cant install Windows 7 on a dell latitude e6400. It always skips the installing process

Tags: boot

I tried a few things to install Windows 7 on the dell latitude e6400. I updated the bios but I also wasn't able to install Windows 7. When i get into the boot menu i select DVD but the Computer always skips the installation. I tried to restart the notebook and all that stuff :) I hope you can give me some helpfull tipps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are booting in legacy mode if your notebook supports UEFI.

Windows 7 does not provide EFI support, hence you need to boot in legacy mode.

Comment: My E6500 (same laptop, smaller screen) with its old firmware was BIOS only.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first just to check

- is the installation DVD original factory-burnt or self-burnt?
- did you go into the BIOS and set the DVD as a first booting device?
- what do you mean with selecting DVD on boot menu? maybe on a separate boot menu got with a Fx key, or?
- did you see this -> Press any key to boot from CD or DVD ..... ?
- what happened then next?

Despite the questions above, true or false, an assumption is the DVD may be somehow corrupted. More detailed answer may follow, after knowing more details.

Comment: the DVD is original factory-burnt, yes i set the DVD as the first booting device, when you press F12 on a dell latitude menu you can select from which device you want to boot, and i didn't see "press any key to boot from CD or DVD", after i click at the boot menu that i want to boot from DVD a Cursor blinks in the upper right Corner and then the normal Windows XP starts booting .

Comment: @Paul98 OK, thanks for the status review. The next step could be checking the DVD on some other machine. If it doesn't boot there, then it's somehow corrupted. If it do boot, then the problem may be on the BIOS itself, as not accepting the DVD boot despite defined by two ways, so, a refreshed or updated BIOS could clear the problem.